# R - Find max frequency and replace value without using loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, replace, max

I have a physician claims dataset where physicians are able to submit claims under different specialties. I want to find the most frequently used specialty submitted by each physician and replace all specialty values with their most commonly used specialty.

```
physician <- c("Mary","Mary","Mary","Mary","Mary","Bob","Bob","Bob")
specialty <- c("GP","PED","DERM","ANES","GP","DERM","GP","DERM")
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(physician,specialty))

data
physician   specialty
Mary        GP
Mary        PED
Mary        DERM
Mary        ANES
Mary        GP
Bob         DERM
Bob         GP
Bob         DERM
```

I am looking for a script that will output the following without using a `for loop`:

```
data
physician   specialty
Mary        GP
Mary        GP
Mary        GP
Mary        GP
Mary        GP
Bob         DERM
Bob         DERM
Bob         DERM
```

The actual data.frame itself has a lot more columns and physicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of tapply. It groups the data and applies a function to each group.

```
physician_max <- tapply(data$specialty, data$physician,
                        function(s) {
                            counts <- table(s)
                            names(counts)[which.max(counts)]
                        })
data$specialty <- physician_max[data$physician]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t <- table(data) #summarise your data.frame
indicator <- apply(t, # apply on the table
                   1, # margin
                   function(x) names(which.max(x))) #find the name for the max value
data$specialty <- indicator[ data$physician] #assign the vector
data  # print your new df
```

Comment: This will probably not work if the data.frame has more columns (as OP stated) because `names(which.max(x))` will probably be NULL.